# Unable to view grid in admin side in magento

Tags: magento, grid

Tried developing one module in admin side in magento but unable to see the grid in admin side. Just need to show grid at the moment with the labels defined along with the data from database. Following is the code related to my module Where News is the namespace and Demo is the module-name.

**Code related to indexController.php**

```
<?php
    class News_Demo_AdminHtml_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
    {
        protected function _initAction()
        {
            $this->loadLayout()->_setActiveMenu('demo/set_time')
                ->_addBreadcrumb('test Manager','test Manager');
            //echo "<pre>"; print_r($this);echo "</pre>";exit;
            return $this;
        }
        public function indexAction()
        {
            $this->_initAction();
            $this->renderLayout();
        }        
    }
?>
```

**Code related to grid container**

```
class News_Demo_Block_Adminhtml_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_demo';
        $this->_blockgroup = 'demo';
        $this->_headerText = 'News Management';
        $this->_addButtonLabel = 'Add News';
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

**Code related to grid.php which displays the grid.**

```
<?php

class News_Demo_Block_Adminhtml_Demo_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('newsGrid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    }
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('demo/demo')->getCollection();
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('id',
            array(
                'header' => 'ID',
                'align' =>'right',
                'width' => '50px',
                'index' => 'id_pfay_test',
            ));
        $this->addColumn('title',
            array(
                'header' => 'Title',
                'align' =>'left',
                'index' => 'title',
            ));
        $this->addColumn('description', array(
            'header' => 'Description',
            'align' =>'left',
            'index' => 'description',
        ));
        $this->addColumn('createdDate', array(
            'header' => 'Date',
            'align' =>'left',
            'index' => 'createdDate',
        ));
        $this->addColumn('img', array(
            'header' => 'Image',
            'align' =>'left',
            'index' => 'img',
        ));
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('id' => $row->getId()));
    }
}
?>
```

**Code related to config.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

    <config>
        <modules>
            <News_Demo>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
            </News_Demo>
        </modules>

        <frontend>
            <routers>
                <news>
                    <use>standard</use>
                    <args>
                        <module>News_Demo</module>
                        <frontName>news</frontName>
                    </args>
                </news>
            </routers>
            <layout>
                <updates>
                    <news_demo>
                        <file>demo.xml</file>
                    </news_demo>
                </updates>
            </layout>
        </frontend>

        <admin>
            <routers>
                <demo>
                    <use>admin</use>
                    <args>
                        <module>News_Demo</module>
                        <frontName>adminnews</frontName>
                    </args>
                </demo>
            </routers>
        </admin>
        <adminhtml>
            <layout>
                <updates>
                    <demo>
                        <file>
                            demo.xml
                        </file>
                    </demo>
                </updates>
            </layout>
            <menu>
                <demo translate="title" module="adminhtml">
                    <title>News</title>
                    <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                    <children>
                        <set_time>
                            <title>Add News</title>
                            <action>adminnews/adminhtml_index</action>
                        </set_time>
                    </children>
                </demo>
            </menu>
        </adminhtml>

        <global>
            <blocks>
                <demo>
                    <class>News_Demo_Block</class>
                </demo>
            </blocks>
            <!--<models>
                <news_demo>
                    <class>News_Demo_Model</class>
                    <resourceModel>news_demo_mysql4</resourceModel>
                </news_demo>
                <news_demo_mysql4>
                    <class>News_Demo_Model_Mysql4</class>
                    <entities>
                        <news_demo>
                            <table>news_demo</table>
                        </news_demo>
                    </entities>
                </news_demo_mysql4>
            </models>-->
            <models>
                <demo>
                    <class>News_Demo_Model</class>
                    <resourceModel>demo_mysql4</resourceModel>
                </demo>
                <demo_mysql4>
                    <class>News_Demo_Model_Mysql4</class>
                    <entities>
                        <demo>
                            <table>demo_news</table>
                        </demo>
                    </entities>
                </demo_mysql4>
            </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

add your module design layout in your adminhtml layout and give name like demo.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <demo_adminhtml_demo_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="{Your grid block}" name="demo" />
        </reference>
    </demo_adminhtml_demo_index>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

$this->_blockgroup = 'demo';

Here the g should be capital G, this is the problem i was facing.

it should be like this

$this->_blockGroup = 'demo';